# *ngFor displaying 2 arrays in alternate way in Angular 4

Tags: arrays, angular, ngfor

I'm creating a chatbot in angular 4 and I'm struggling a bit on how to display the messages properly. On enter I simply parse the value which is sent for computation, and at the same time stored into an array userMessage. When I get the response from the bot, I store that into another array called botMessage. Assuming I sent 3 messages this is how the output will display:

- UserMessage1
- UserMessage2
- UserMessage3
- BotMessage1
- BotMessage2
- BotMessage3

The output that I want to display is the one of a normal chat so it would be:

- UserMessage1
- BotMessage1
- UserMessage2
- BotMessage2
- UserMessage3
- BotMessage3

This is my html code

```
  <ul >
    <li class="bubble user-message" *ngFor = "let message of userMessage ">
      {{message}}
    </li>
    <li class ="bubble bot-message" *ngFor = "let message of botMessage">
      {{message}}
    </li>

  </ul>
```

Any suggestions? Thank you very much

edit this is my typescript code:

> inputField

```
//this is called when enter is pressed. apiCall would be the service
onEnter(value: string) {
    this.value = value;
    this.userMessage.push(value);        
    this.apiCall.postValue(value this.output );
    this.botMessage = this.apiCall.getMessages();
    this.chat.displayMessages();
  } //on enter
```

> this is my service

```
private messages = [];
postValue(value:string, output:any){
  this.http.post('/APIconversation', {"input":value})
  .map(response=>response.json())
  .subscribe(
      data => {
            // Read the result field from the JSON response.
            output = data.text;                


            this.messages.push(output);
     }
  )
}

getMessages(){
    return this.messages;
}
```

> this is where I parse the arrays to the html to be rendered

```
@Input() userMessage: InputFieldComponent; //gets the array userMessage from the parent (input-field)   
@Input() botMessage: InputFieldComponent; //gets the array botMessage from the parent (input-field)   

displayMessages() {
    this.messages = this.apiCall.getMessages();   
}
```

Comment: It just shows your model is not adequate. Instead of two arrays, use a single one, containing all the messages, or containing objects containing a user message and the associated bot response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**updated answer**

I recommend to store your bot-messages in an dictionary, with the key of the user-message like this:

```
botMessage = {};
userMessage = [];

onEnter(value: string) {
    this.userMessage.push(value); 
    var context = this.apiCall.getContext(value); 
    this.apiCall.postValue(value, context, this.output);

    const botMessages = this.apiCall.getMessages();

    // Add all bot messages depending on their user messages
    for(const message of botMessages) {
        this.botMessage[message.userMessageId] = message;
    }
}
```

Implied, that your bot-message has the info to which user-message it depends.
With this structure, you can easily access the answer in your html like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="bubble" *ngFor="let message of userMessage">
      <div class="user-message>{{ message }}</div>
      <div *ngIf="botMessage[message.id]" class="bot-message>
        {{ botMessage[message.id] }}
      </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Also I'm pretty sure, you have some asynchronous problems, but that's another chapter :-)

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that solution, but if I do that, the message and answer will display simultaneously. It can happen that the answer will take some time to process (say 30sec) I want to display the input straight away and then the response as soon as it arrives to the UI

Comment: From what do you get your data? Http calls?  I think the solution for you are observables, but I need a but more information :-)

Comment: Yeah, I do :) I basically take the input from the user and push it to the userMessage array and display it. The input is asynchronously sent through an http request as a json object to a server, which will send back an output. the output is then stored to the botMessage array and then displayed

Comment: So for each user-message will be one bot-message?

Comment: Exactly. one on one

Comment: I've updated my answer. I hope this will solve your problem

Comment: hi, sorry for the late reply, and before anything thanks for your suggestions. There are few things I don't understand about your code, I hope you don't mind explaining it to me. So first thing is what it userMessage in this case? is it the array? I'm not totally sure. I assume that userMessage:UserMessage would be the service where I store the message from the user?

Comment: Yes, it is the array. Can you provide your typescript code? Then, I will update my answer :-)

Comment: I've added it, thank you very much for your time and patience, I will be learning a lot from this.

Comment: Answer updates. I hope that will help you get it running :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could merge these arrays into one and use a condition to check the bot and user based on a object property, you can't achieve with two arrays,

```
  <div *ngFor="let message of Messages"
        <div *ngIf="message.type === 'User'">
                <user-message-item [message]="message"></sender-message-item>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="message.type === 'Bot'">
                <bot-message-item [message]="message"></receiver-message-item>
            </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: how can I set an object property to an array?

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your data model, you could use an index:

```
  <ul *ngFor = "let message of userMessage; let i=index;">
    <li>
      {{ message }}
    </li>
    <li> {{ botMessage[i] }} </li>
  </ul>
```

Then adjust where to place the *ngFor.

The result is the one you would expect.

[Link to plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/0q92cGXSsU7KyezeVojd?p=preview)

You would though need to check for lengths as they might be different between arrays, I'd recommend evaluating your data model.